# Core Data Leaking Memory?

Tags: iphone, core-data, instruments, memory-leaks

I keep seeing what appears to be a memory leak - but I can't tell what to do. It looks like a memory leak in Core Data. I can see the LAST method I explicitly invoke in Objective-C, but I'm not creating any object there. I'm saving something and Core Data is leaking memory according to **Leaks**. Am I reading this incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: Why did someone downrate this question without a comment or point for me to take from that?

Comment: Without some source code, this is impossible to help with. You say you're not leaking but all you did was post a screenshot.

Now, while leaks in system frameworks like Core Data are possible, my humble suggestion would be that it is more likely something you are doing / your code that has the problem.

Core Data is used by hundreds of thousands of developers and subjected to heavy testing.

That said, if you do indeed find a leak, you should submit it to Apple's Bug Reporter.

Comment: The tail end of my original post has the question. "Am I reading this correct?" FWIW, the question is not about the source code, it is about the screenshot. The LEAKS row in the top says I have a leak - that is the spike you see. The column in the table below says 1 leak of 32 bytes. My question is then - after unfolding the stack trace ... how do I read this actual screen shot? I am sure you are correct, I don't think Core Data is necessary leaking. I am actually asking how to read the screenshot. The leaf of the stack trace is in Core Data ... which is what motivated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been informed:

> There is a known memory leak in NSFetchedResultsController during the save.
>   The fix will be available in 3.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar trace in Leaks and it looks to me like Core Data or NSFetchedResultsController is leaking memory. I've attached my own screenshot. My guess is that yes, Core Data is leaking memory.

[image]

[See larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sbwoodside/3871165163/sizes/o/)